# pass parameter to crystal report

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I write this code but it have this error.

> "Run-time error '20553': Invalid parameter field name"

can anyone help me to solve it?

```vb
With CR

  .ParameterFields(0) = "start;" + CStr(Form1.cmbMonth.Text) & ";True"
  .ParameterFields(1) = "end;" + CStr(Form1.cmbYear.Text) & ";True"

  .ReportFileName = App.Path & "\Report\Report1.rpt"

  .SelectionFormula = "{SW.dtaMonth}>=date('" & Format(Form1.cmbMonth.Text) & "') and {SW.dtaYear}<=date(" & Format(Form1.cmbYear.Text) & ")"

  .WindowTitle = "PG Variable Overhead Report" 'title of report
  .Action = 1 'Will Show The Report

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
With CR
  .ParameterFields(0) = "start;" & CStr(Form1.cmbMonth.Text) & ";True"
  .ParameterFields(1) = "end;" & CStr(Form1.cmbYear.Text) & ";True"
  .ReportFileName = App.Path & "\Report\Report1.rpt"
  .SelectionFormula = "{SW.dtaMonth}>=date('" & Format(Form1.cmbMonth.Text) & "') and {SW.dtaYear}<=date(" & Format(Form1.cmbYear.Text) & ")"
  .WindowTitle = "PG Variable Overhead Report" 'title of report   .Action = 1 'Will Show The Report
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Crystal changed the way parameters are passed to external (non-embedded) reports at some point, but I'm not sure which version they did that with. The version I have is 10, and parameters are passed in that using this method:

```
.ParameterFields(n).AddCurrentValue "PARAMETER"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 CR.ParameterFields.Item(1).AddCurrentValue "YourValue"
```